# Key Pressing System PyGame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a basic pong game and want to make a system where a button press makes the paddle goes up or down. I'm fairly new to PyGame and here's my code so far.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import*
def Pong():
 pygame.init()
 DISPLAY=pygame.display.set_mode((600,400),0,32)
 pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")
 BLACK=(0,0,0)
 WHITE=(255,255,255)
 RED=(255,0,0)
 DISPLAY.fill(BLACK)
 while True:
  def P(b):
   pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,WHITE,(50,b,50,10))
  xx=150
  P(xx)
  for event in pygame.event.get():
   if event.type==KEYUP and event.key==K_W:
    P(xx+10)
    xx=xx+10
    pygame.display.update()
   elif event.type==QUIT:
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: So where is your exact problem that you need help with?

Answer (score 2):

Please [read](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/MoveIt.html) some tutorials and/or [docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/). This is really basic and if you don't get this right it will bite you later.

Anyway, here's how it could look:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((600,400))

paddle = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 10, 50)
paddle.midleft = DISPLAY.get_rect().midleft

speed = 10

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            raise SystemExit(0)

    keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    dy = keystate[pygame.K_s] - keystate[pygame.K_w]
    paddle.move_ip(0, dy * speed)

    DISPLAY.fill(pygame.Color("black"))
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, pygame.Color("white"), paddle)
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(30)
```

That is *ok* for Pong but I still wouldn't write my game like this. So read some tutorials and maybe try [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you really want to improve your code.

Comment: It is not often that I upvote an answer in the pygame tag, but this one does everything right.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, do you know any good websites for tutorials because I am still new to this

Comment: @RutvikMarathe [How do I move an Image?](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/MoveIt.html), [Chimp Tutorial, Line by Line](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/chimp/ChimpLineByLine.html), [Sprite Module Introduction](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/SpriteIntro.html), [Newbie Guide](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/newbieguide.html). I found these especially helpful.